# Azure Data Factory DYNAMICALLY partition a csv/txt file based on rowcount

Tags: azure, dynamic, partitioning, azure-data-factory

I am using azure dataflow to transform delimited files (csv/txt) to json. But I want to separate the files dynamically based on a max row count of 5,000 because I will not know the row count every time. So if I have a csv file with 10,000 rows the pipeline will output two equal json files, file1.json and file2.json. What is the best way to actually get the row count of my sources and the correct n number of partitions based on that row count within Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question. Look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77981614/6234075

Answer (score 1):

We can't specify the row number to split the csv file. The closest workaround is specify the partition of the sink.

For example, I have a csv file contains 700 rows data. I successfully copy to two equal json files.

My source csv data in Blob storage:
[image]

**Sink settings:** each partition output a new file:  `json1.json` and `json2.json`:

[image]

**Optimize:**

1. Partition operation: `Set partition`
2. Partition type: `Dynamic partition`
3. Number of partitions: `2` (means split the csv data to 2 partitions)
4. Stored ranges in columns: `id`(split based on the `id` column)

[image]

Run the Data flow and the csv file will split to two json files which each contains 350 rows data.

For your situation, the csv file with 10,000 rows the pipeline will output two equal json files(each contains 5,000 row data).

Comment: I think this solution really only works if you know how many rows there are in the first place - if the file has 250K rows you'll end up with two 125K row files because you've hardcoded "2". In order to really control this, you'll need to rely on something other than ADF to capture the total row count, like an Azure Function. Then you can use that calculated value in a round robin set partition.

Comment: Thank you. But how about doing it dynamically?. I won't know exactly how many total rows I will have every time. It could be 10,000 or 1,000,000. Partitioning large files into n number of output files with 5,000 rows each?

Comment: @DimejiOlayinka yeah, I know. Per my experience about Data Factory, I tried and tested, but still not we find a way to achieve that. The most closest way is using partition. May it could add an operation to specify the rows in each partition. You could also add the request in Data Factory feedback:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory

Comment: @LeonYue Do you guys have any current/updated idea how could we achieve dynamic partition? What is the best practice for this? I am working on a dataset with 60M rows from Kusto (ADX).

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use the mod or % operator.

1. To start with set a surrogate key on the CSV file or use any sequential key in the data.
2. [Add a aggregate step with a group by clause that is your key % row count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5FLH.png)
3. Set the Aggregates function to collect()

Your output should now be a array of rows with the expected count in each.