# Process more than 5000 rows from lookup activity in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to paas Id in another activity in data factory .Id is stored in blob storage in json format.
I am using Look-Up in my activity which will fetch data .But my pipeline gets failed when data is more than 5000.I need a solution for this.I didnt understand the existing solution in stack overflow.

Comment: Which solution is stack overflow have you looked at - can you add the link please?

Comment: Yes sure..I have tried this but couldnt able to succeed as i have dynamic count of rows.An activity diagram implementation would have more helpfil for me as i am new to ADF. Please find below the link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/42083/how-to-process-more-than-5000-records-in-lookup-ac.html

Comment: OK that solution looks like the right approach - have used that before.
However, did you query a SQL table to get the id's into blob in the first place?

Comment: Yes..i have cosmos db container from where I am fetching only I'd of items and storing in blob container. Then I am using lookup to get the ID and paas each I'd inside foreach loop activities.

Comment: I would request you to if possible can u please upload activitiy diagram for lookup where u have used it.

Comment: Sure, but let me understand.  So you are getting >5000 ids out of cosmos into csv using copy activity.  Then you want to process each id in the loop.  What is 'process' here?  Are you querying the same cosmos based on the ids you have pre-selected?  Or is the id a key in another dataset - like, select x from y where id in (_big list_)?

Comment: 1.I am getting >5k ids from cosmos db conatiner in json format and storing these ids in blob storage using copy activity.
2.Then Using lookup i am counting the ids and set variable and then apply forloop.
3.Inside for loop i am calling web activity where i need to pass each id as dynamic variable in post method of an API in body.

Answer (score 2):

Ah ok, well you cannot use OFFSET/LIMIT pagination sensibly in Cosmos and ADF cannot use continuation tokens.  Also you cannot LOOKUP >5000 results from blob or paginate the blob output.

If I had this problem I would try the following based on this idea [Azure Data Factory DYNAMICALLY partition a csv/txt file based on rowcount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63138165/azure-data-factory-dynamically-partition-a-csv-txt-file-based-on-rowcount).

- Use dataflow to get the data from cosmos and write to *several* json files using partitioning, each < 5000 rows (using the method described in the comment on the above link - using a surrogate and the MOD operator)
- ForLoop over those blobs
- Have a nested pipeline that does the lookup and calls the API, as you have now - now the lookup will only have max 5000 items