# Is there a way to partition data in Azure Data Factories to fill files until max rows value is hit?

Tags: java, azure, apache-spark, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to partition my data into groups that write their data into csv files that prioritize hitting the max number of rows per file, rather than evenly distributing the rows across multiple files.

For example, if I have 5001 records and my max row size per file is 1000, I want 6 partitions, 5 of which have 1000 files and the 6th file having 1 record.

Is this possible in Azure? I've tried doing it manually in my Java code, but it seems like manually partitioning queried data from azure is non-deterministic and comes out with duplicates across files.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can easily divide the csv file into multiple files with specific maximum rows and remaining rows in the last file.

Please follow the steps below:

1. Create the Azure Data Factory service using Azure Portal. [Follow link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal).
2. You also need to create Storage Account. [Follow link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=azure-portal). Create two containers, **input** and **output**. In **input** container, upload your CSV file which you will partition in data factory.
3. Now go to the data factory studio. Click on the **Manage** symbol available on left side and then click on **+New** to create **Linked Service** to connect with your blob container.

[image]x

4. Select on **Azure Blob Storage** option and click on **Continue**.
5. Now fill the details as shown below. Give **Name** to this linked service. **Select Subscription**. **Select storage account** where your csv is available. **Test connection** and click on **Create**. This will be used when we'll create the source dataset.

[image]

6. Similarly, create another linked service with same details which will be used in sink dataset.
7. Now, go to the Pencil symbol (left side). Click on **Dataset** and select **New Dataset** from drop down.
8. Select **Azure Blob Storage => DemilitedText**.
9. Give **Name**, **select linked service you created in step 5**. Select your **input csv file** and click Ok.
   [image]
10. Repeat steps 7 to 9. Create another Dataset with different name for **output** Container where your group files will be saved after partition. **Simply select output container in File path.**
11. Follow the below steps to create your pipeline. **Pencil symbol -> Pipeline -> New Pipeline**. Search for **copy data** activity and drag and drop in white space. Give any name to your pipeline. In the **Source** tab, select the Source dataset which you have created in step 9. This dataset will be treated as input for your copy activity.
    [image]
12. In the **Sink** Tab, select the **Sink Dataset** you create in step 10. Give the **File extension .csv** and **Max rows per file 1000**(or number as per your requirement). This dataset will be treated as sink where your partitioned files will be stored. Click on Publish to save your changes. Wait to changes to published.

Then as final step, click on **Add Trigger** and select **Trigger now** option to run your pipeline.
[image]

You can check all the partitioned files in your storage account output container. You can observe that all the files except the last one will have max rows which your mentioned above. And the last file will only have remaining rows.
[image]

Comment: This should be marked as an acceptable answer. +1 from my end.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Window Columns called row_no=rowNumber() and partition_no=ceil(rowNumber()/$records_per_partition). Use this partition_no in sink to create partition by key.

[image]

[image]